# Удаление образа docker

Tags: linux, docker

Такой командой я могу убедиться, что образ `Ubuntu` установлен:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu                latest              104bec311bcd        4 weeks ago         129 MB
```

Допустим я где-то накосячил и хочу начать с чистого листа. Удаляю образ:

```
$ docker rmi -f ubuntu
Untagged: ubuntu:latest
Untagged: ubuntu@sha256:7a64bc9c8843b0a8c8b8a7e4715b7615e4e1b0d8ca3c7e7a76ec8250899c397a
Deleted: sha256:104bec311bcdfc882ea08fdd4f5417ecfb1976adea5a0c237e129c728cb7eada
```

Теперь проверяю удалился ли он:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Да, образа действительно нет. Теперь я хочу скачать новый образ и вижу это:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu

b3e1c725a85f: Already exists 
4daad8bdde31: Already exists 
63fe8c0068a8: Already exists 
4a70713c436f: Already exists 
bd842a2105a8: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:7a64bc9c8843b0a8c8b8a7e4715b7615e4e1b0d8ca3c7e7a76ec8250899c397a
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

Если запустить этот образ, то я увижу свой косячный. Как мне удалить образ целиком и установить чистый ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если выполните вот такую команду

```
docker images -a
```

То увидите, что у вас много промежуточных образов. Вы можете их удалить по одному, но лучше попробуйте вот такую последовательность команд

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Первая попробует удалить все контейнеры (если контейнер запущен, то он не удалится). Вторая удалит все образы "висящие" образ - это образы без репозитория и тэга и которые не являются промежуточными для других образов.